What is que doing in "ella tiene que ducharse hoy"?
"ella tiene que ducharse hoy" the translation of it is "She has to shower today".
The meaning stays the same without "que", I don't see anything directly or indirectly. What does the "que" convey in the context?

It has the same purpose that "to" in your English version. What is doing that "to" there? It establishes the relation between the two verbs.

@RubioRic Now it makes much more sense. Thank you. I will consider it as my answer.

You're wrong when you say the meaning stays the same without que, since "ella tiene ducharse hoy" is just wrong and nobody speaks like that. I'm not a linguist, so I can't explain why, but I'm a native speaker and I've never used an expression like that and I've never heard something like that from another native speaker. Other examples: "tienes que ir a comprar cuadernos" is right, but "tienes ir a comprar cuadernos" is wrong. "tienes que sentarte" is right, "tienes sentarte" is just wrong. When you "have to" do something, in English, you "tienes que" hacer algo in Spanish.

Es un conector lingüístico, por lo general se le llama conjunción (una unión) entre palabras o frases para un significado lógico en Español.
Por ejemplo en la frase Muestra lo que has hecho hoy (Show what you have done today).
Sucede lo mismo que la palabra en ingles to
To eat = comer. Pero eat sin el to también es comer, entonces que hace el to en to eat??

It is an idiom. From the dictionary entry on tener

tr. Denota la necesidad o determinación de hacer aquello que expresa una cláusula posterior introducida por que. Tendré que salir.

Since comments are ephemeral I copy here part of @jachguarte's comment "You're wrong when you say the meaning stays the same without que, since "ella tiene ducharse hoy" is just wrong and nobody speaks like that."
When I said tener que is an idiom I meant that it is not something which you can translate by translating the individual words. It is better to accept that Spanish is different from English and has its own idioms.
